# Cómo modificar datos en un ArrayList de tipo objeto

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist

Estoy haciendo un programa el cual se utilice para meter datos de las personas. El programa debe contener un menú donde esté alta, cambios y bajas, en los cambios debo de buscar el nombre de la persona al cual le voy a cambiar los datos y decir cual dato cambiarlo y eso es con lo que batallo.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Datos {
    public static void khe() {
        int a = 0,bandera=0,cont=0,b=0,c=0,d=0;
        String aux=null,nombre3=null;
        ArrayList<Tipodatos> nombre=new ArrayList<Tipodatos>();
        BufferedReader nombreshido=new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        do {
            try {
                System.out.println("1. Altas");
                System.out.println("2. Cambios");
                System.out.println("3. Bajas");
                System.out.println("4. Salir");
                aux=nombreshido.readLine();
                a=(int) Double.parseDouble(aux);
            }catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Esa no es una opcion viable");
            }
            switch (a){
                case 1:
                    Tipodatos mostrar3=new Tipodatos();
                    for(cont=0;cont<1; cont++) {
                        Tipodatos nombrekrakk=new Tipodatos();
                        try {
                            System.out.println("Altas");
                            System.out.println("===============================");
                            System.out.println("Escribe tu nombre");
                            nombrekrakk.nombres=nombreshido.readLine();
                            System.out.println("Escribe tu edad");
                            nombrekrakk.edad=Integer.parseInt(nombreshido.readLine());
                            System.out.println("Escribe tu hobie");
                            nombrekrakk.hobie=nombreshido.readLine();
                            nombre.add(nombrekrakk);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("No agarra tus datos");
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Tipodatos mostrar2=new Tipodatos();
                    Tipodatos nombrekrak=new Tipodatos();

                    for(cont=0;cont<1;cont++) {
                        try {
                            System.out.println("Cambios");
                            System.out.println("===============================");
                            System.out.println("Escribe el nombre que desea buscar");
                            nombre3=nombreshido.readLine();

                            boolean khe;
                            int karrayes=0;
                            for(int i=0;i<=nombre.size();i++) {
                                Tipodatos nombresss= new Tipodatos();
                                nombresss=(Tipodatos) nombre.get(i);
                                khe=nombre3.equals(nombresss);
                                if(khe=true) {
                                    karrayes=i;
                                    i=nombre.size();
                                }
                            }
                            mostrar2=(Tipodatos) nombre.get(karrayes);
                            System.out.println("nombre: "+mostrar2.nombres);
                            System.out.println("1.Cambiar el nombre");
                            System.out.println("2. edad");
                            System.out.println("3. hobie");
                            aux=nombreshido.readLine();
                            d=(int) Double.parseDouble(aux);
                            switch(d) {
                                case 1:
                                    System.out.println("Escribe el nombre a cambiar");
                                    nombrekrak.nombres=nombreshido.readLine();
                                    nombre.set(karrayes,mostrar2.nombress);

                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    System.out.println("Escribe la edad a cambiar");
                                    nombrekrak.edad=Integer.parseInt(nombreshido.readLine());

                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                    System.out.println("Escribe el hobie a cambiar");
                                    nombrekrak.hobie=nombreshido.readLine();
                                    nombre.set(a,nombrekrak);
                            }

                        }catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("No se detecto ningun caracter");
                        }
                    }

                    for(cont=0;cont<1;cont++) {
                        System.out.println("Persona No. "+cont);
                        mostrar2=(Tipodatos) nombre.get(cont);
                        System.out.println("Nombre "+mostrar2.nombress);
                        System.out.println("Edad "+mostrar2.edad);
                        System.out.println("Hobie "+mostrar2.hobie);
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Tipodatos mostrar=new Tipodatos();
                    for(cont=0;cont<1; cont++) {
                        Tipodatos nombrekrakk=new Tipodatos();
                        try {
                            System.out.println("Bajas");
                            System.out.println("===============================");
                            System.out.println("Teclea el numero al cual desea eliminar");
                            b=Integer.parseInt(nombreshido.readLine());
                            nombre.remove(b);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("No se detecto ningun caracter");
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Haz salido del programa");
                    bandera=1;
            }
        }while(bandera==0);
    }
}
```

> En la clase `TipoDatos` se encuentran las siguientes variables

```
import java.util.Collection;

public class Tipodatos {
    Tipodatos nombress;
    String nombres;

    int edad;
    String hobie;
    String nombre2; 
}
```

Comment: Cual es exactamente tu problema? No funciona, no sabes como determinar a quien cambiar, da algun error, no guarda, etc?

Comment: No guarda los datos que cambio